# Vue composition API renders {value: 0} instead of plain value for nested field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to create a component that can be used via destructuring and as js object.
Destructuring works fine, but with js object, I'm forced to write `obj.field.value` instead of just `obj.field`. Is it expected behavior?
I'm using [composition-api plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api).

Playground: https://jsfiddle.net/3mzve8oy/21/

```html
<div id="app">
  <h2 @click="ctx.fn">{{ ctx.counter }} {{counter}} </h2>
</div>
```

```js
const { reactive, toRefs } = VueCompositionAPI;

const useCounter = () => {
  const ctx = reactive({
    counter: 2,
    // ...
  });
  
  const fn = () => {
    console.log('Called', ctx.counter);
  }
    
  setInterval(() => ctx.counter += 1, 1000);
  return {...toRefs(ctx), fn};
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  setup() {
    const ctx = useCounter();
    const { counter } = useCounter();
    return { ctx, counter };
  }
})
```

Expected output: `0 0` 
Actual output: `{ "value": 0 } 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. See [*Ref Unwrapping* docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping), which describe your exact scenario:

> When a ref is returned as a property on the render context (the object returned from [setup()](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html)) and accessed in the template, it automatically shallow unwraps the inner value. Only the nested ref will require `.value` in the template:
>
> ```html
> <template>
>   <div>
>     <span>{{ count }}</span>
>     <button @click="count ++">Increment count</button>
>     <button @click="nested.count.value ++">Nested Increment count</button>
>   </div>
> </template>
>
> <script>
>   import { ref } from 'vue'
>   export default {
>     setup() {
>       const count = ref(0)
>       return {
>         count,
>
>         nested: {
>           count
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time seeing `vue-composition-api`, but in their docs it looks like they use `value` as design choice in objects to preserve reactivity on the object if it gets passed around the app.

see here:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#setup-component-option

> ref takes the argument and returns it wrapped within an object with a value property, which can then be used to access or mutate the value of the reactive variable:*

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

const counter = ref(0)

console.log(counter) // { value: 0 }
console.log(counter.value) // 0

counter.value++
console.log(counter.value) // 1
```